# what is the possibility to create a SQL user to connect through JDBC only not with SSMS and other tools?

Tags: sql-authentication

Maybe my understanding was not clear about user authentication in MSSQL. I am very new to DataBase subjects.

Thought of checking with the experts here.

I am planning to provide access to SQL users to connect only via JDBC from the backend code.
and the user should not connect via SSMS or other tools.

please share how that can achieve or possible or not

Comment: Little experience with MSSQL, but wouldn't it be easier to reject all connection attempts from other systems than the backend?

Comment: Who is the user in this case?...application users of an application you're creating, or other developers writing code?

Comment: Utterly impossible: there is no real way for the server to tell who is connecting, only whether they are authorized. I suggest you take steps to secure the login credentials. Note that Windows Authentication does not use passwords and may be more secure for your purposes

Comment: @J.D. it's for other developers who write code, and SQL users to be used in the code.